# How to write an SQL query to get rows with the same prefix

Tags: sql, query-optimization, prefix

everyone;

I am working on a database where path information are stored, one simplified table is shown below

```
path_id | path value
1         //a/b/c/d
2         //a/b/e
3         //a/b
4         //a/bcd
```

So here is the question, how can I get information where has '//a/b' as the prefix? In this case, the result should be:

```
path_id | path value
1         //a/b/c/d
2         //a/b/e
3         //a/b
```

I am seeking for a more elegant and optimized query, other than using logic operators like 'OR'.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE path_value like '//a/b/%' OR path_value = '//a/b'
```

Note the extra slash before the wild card in the first part of the `WHERE` statement.  This will exclude **//a/bcd**.

Answer (score 0):

the % acts as a wild card so it anything can follow that part.

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE path_value like '//a/b/%' OR path_value = '//a/b'
```

Comment: That will still pick up path_id 4

Comment: Right, I didn't look close enough.  I didn't realize he didn't want 4.  I'll edit it.